How to access node_modules from host while using Docker Compose for web application development?
I've recently been deploying a web application using Docker Compose. I want to run npm install during the image build stage and mount the development files along with node_modules so I can modify the code on the host. Here's what I did:
FROM  node:16.20

USER root

RUN npm install -g @quasar/cli && \
    npm install -g @vue/cli && \
    npm install -g @vue/cli-init 

ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096

ENV CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true

RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./quasar/package*.json /app

RUN npm --registry https://npmreg.proxy.ustclug.org/ install --verbose

CMD ["quasar", "dev"]

frontend:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile_quasar
  container_name: pe_frontend
  volumes: 
    - ./quasar:/app:rw
    - node_modules:/app/node_modules
  restart: "no"
  command: "quasar dev"
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
  environment:
    - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
  ports:
    - "38080:9000"
volumes:
  node_modules:
    driver: local

The app development server runs well in the container, but I can't access node_modules from the host, so my IDE doesn't recognize the modules in my code. Is there a way to configure the volume so I can access the node_modules directory from the host? Do I need to copy the node_modules directory or run npm install on the host? Doing that would render the build stage npm install redundant.

Why do you want to modify the "node_modules" folder? ... mount the development files along with node_modules so I can modify the code on the host.

Do you actually need Docker as part of this setup at all?  A container will intrinsically hide development tools inside the container and normally the host and container filesystems are separate; can you use Node without Docker, and avoid these complexities?

@Marc I don't want to modify "node_modules" manually. Its presence on the host is for IDE package recognition only.

@DavidMaze Actually, this is part of a larger project that includes a database, API server, a monitoring system, and more. Therefore, I need docker-compose to manage all the images and containers.

Assuming you don't want to manually modify files inside your node_modules file  (why would you?), remember that bind mounts write from your host to the container, so your first like in your docker-compose ./quasar:/app:rw will write the contents from your host into the container in the /app directory.
Assuming all your actual source code is inside a src directory, you can change your docker-compose to:
frontend:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile_quasar
  container_name: pe_frontend
  volumes: 
    - ./quasar/src:/app/src:rw
  restart: "no"
  command: "quasar dev"
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
  environment:
    - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
  ports:
    - "38080:9000"

And run npm ci on your local.
This way you are only bind mounting your source code but can keep an independent set of node_modules folders.
